# Not able to build node js project for a specifc imported library

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am importing libraries in my vue.js project. For Library1 alone there are no errors. When i run my vue node js project build for library 2 i am importing , it always fails at below line and gets stuck with message 'building for production'.

```
Could not find implementations for the following rules specified in the configuration:
no-explicit-any
Try upgrading TSLint and/or ensuring that you have all necessary custom rules  installed.
If TSLint was recently upgraded, you may have old rules configured which need to be cleaned up.
```

Is there a way to make this ignore by npm build ?

Below is my .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
      root: true,
      env: {
        node: true
      },
      'extends': [
        'plugin:vue/essential',
        'eslint:recommended',
        '@vue/typescript/recommended'
      ],
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2020,
        ecmaFeatures: {
          legacyDecorators: true,
        },
      },
      rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 0,
        '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore': 'off',
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
   }
  }
```

Do i need to update my tsconfig or tslint to stop checking for this when building production. This happens to only my  vue library projecting i am using.

I use npm link and npm link  to link and install libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way to fix it is by removing tslint. As you Already have eslint. You just have have to install some extra eslint packages

```
npm i -D @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin;
npm i -D @typescript-eslint/parser;
npm i -D eslint;
```

The following is the recommended

```js
module.exports = {
    env: {
        commonjs: true,
        es6: true,
        node: true,
    },
    extends: [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    ],
    globals: {
        Atomics: "readonly",
        SharedArrayBuffer: "readonly",
    },
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    parserOptions: {
        project: "./tsconfig.json",
        ecmaVersion: 2019,
    },
    plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
    rules: {
.....
    }
}
```

#### NOTE:

on your `tsconfig.json`
Add the include section. This as the name says includes the paths of your source files. And exclude does the opposite

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
....
  },
  "exclude": [
    "/node_modules/",
    "./config/"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/**/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```